# A $ 0 $-dimensional topological subspace of $ \Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{N}} $.

Tags: general-topology

Given the space $X(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}, i)$ contains points $(x_{j})_{j\in N}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with only $i$ coordinates rational.

(a) Show that $X(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}, 0)$ is zero-dimensional.

(b) Show that $X(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}, 0)\cup X(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}, 1)$ is not zero-dimensional.

**My attempt** For part (a), from the definition, every points in the space $X(R^N, 0)$ have irrational coordinates. So it means its coordinates belong to the set $R-Q$, and we know that every irrational numbers is between two rational numbers (classical result). Thus, every points is contained in an open set in $R^N$, which is of the form $((q_1,q_2), (q_3, q_4),....)$ where $q_i\in Q$, so the basis of $X(R^N, 0)$ is a union of open sets. On the other hand, every point $(x_j)$ has a closed discrete set ${x_j}$ in $X(R^N,0)$, so the basis sets is also a union of closed sets. Thus, $X(R^N,0)$ is zero-dimensional.

Is my proof above correct? Also, can someone please help me with part (b)? I really got stuck on this part:P

Comment: Can you clarify, by in $ $ signs \mathbb{N} for the natural numbers, and similar for R and the reals, as opposed to this ambiguous boldness. Also could you define what you mean by $w$ please?

Comment: My bad. I edited it.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of my league here, I haven't covered it. @Brian M. Scott, would you be willing to help out here?

Comment: @KB94: It’ll be a bit before I get to it, but I’ll take a look.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Many thanks for your willingness to help, Professor Scott!

Comment: @KB94: I'm sorry:P

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Thanks! I owe you one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s hard to tell, because what you’ve written isn’t entirely clear, but I think that your argument for (a) is not entirely correct. You do indeed want to show that $X(\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},0)$ has a clopen base, but it isn’t clear that you’ve actually done that. I would argue as follows.

> Let $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in X(\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},0)$, and let $U$ be any open nbhd of $x$ in $X(\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},0)$. By the definition of the product topology there are a finite $F\subseteq\Bbb N$ and open intervals $(a_n,b_n)$ in $\Bbb R$ for $n\in F$ such that if $U_n=(a_n,b_n)$ for $n\in F$, and $U_n=\Bbb R$ for $n\in\Bbb N\setminus F$, then $x\in\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n\subseteq U$. Clearly $a_n<x_n<b_n$ for $n\in F$, so there are rational numbers $p_n$ and $q_n$ for $n\in F$ such that $a_n<p_n<x_n<q_n<b_n$. Let $V_n=(p_n,q_n)$ for $n\in F$ and $V_n=\Bbb R$ for $n\in\Bbb N\setminus F$; then $x\in\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n\subseteq\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n\subseteq U$, and
>
> $$\operatorname{cl}_{X(\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},0)}\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}V_n=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n\;,$$
>
> so $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n$ is clopen. Thus, $x$ has a local base of clopen sets, and since $x$ was arbitrary, $X(\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},0)$ is zero-dimensional.

For (b) let’s start by simplifying the notation a little and letting $X_i=X(\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},i)$ for $i\in\Bbb N$ and setting $X=X_0\cup X_1$; $X$ is the set of points of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ with at most one rational coordinate, and we want to show that $X$ is not zero-dimensional. This would certainly follow if we could show that $X$ is path-connected. Let $p=\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in X_0$ be defined by $p_n=\sqrt2$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. (The specific choice of $\sqrt2$ isn’t important: I just want an irrational number.) Let $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in X$ be arbitrary; it suffices to show that there is a path from $x$ to $p$.

Suppose first that $x\in X_0$. We’ll define a continuous $f:[0,1]\to X$ so that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=p$. For $f(t)$ I’ll write $x^{(t)}=\langle x_n^{(t)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Begin by sliding $x_0$ to $p_0$ as $t$ goes from $0$ to $\frac12$, leaving the other coordinates alone:

$$x_n^{(t)}=\begin{cases}
2tp_0+(1-2t)x_0,&\text{if }n=0\\
x_n,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

for $0\le t\le\frac12$. At no point is more than one coordinate rational: the only one that can ever be rational is $x_0^{(t)}$. Then slide $x_1$ to $p_1$ as $t$ goes from $\frac12$ to $\frac34$, leaving the other coordinates alone:

$$x_n^{(t)}=\begin{cases}
(4t-2)p_0+(3-4t)x_1,&\text{if }n=1\\
x_n^{(1/2)},&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

for $\frac12\le t\le\frac34$. Once again, at no point does $x^{(t)}$ have more than one rational coordinate.

Continue in this fashion, sliding $x_n$ to $p_n$ as $t$ goes from $1-2^{-n}$ to $1-2^{-(n+1)}$. I’ll leave it to you to work out the actual formula for $x_n^{(t)}$ on the general interval $1-2^{-n}\le t\le 1-2^{-(n+1)}$ and to verify continuity. (Of course $f(1)=p$.)

Finally, for $x\in X_1$ you can do the same thing, **provided** that you start by fixing up the one coordinate on which $x$ is rational.

Comment: Dear Professor Scott, I was able to obtain the formula for $x_{k}^{(t)}= 2(2^{n}.t - 2^n+1)p_0 +  (2^{n+1}-1-2^{n+1}t)x_n$ if $k=n$, and $x_{k}^{(t)} = x_k$ otherwise. The continuity follows since we only need to check it at values $t=1-2^{-n}$ for n=1,2,...., which is true by definition of $x_{n}^{t}$ for $t\geq 1-2^{-n}$ and $t\leq 1-2^{-n}$. However, why is it continuous at $t=\frac{1}{2}$? Since $x_{0}^{(\frac{1}{2})}= p_0$ for $t\leq \frac{1}{2}$, $x_{0}^{(\frac{1}{2})}=x_0$ for $t\geq {1}{2}$, but $x_0\neq p_0$.

Comment: I tried constructing the similar sequence when $x\in X_1$ by switching the conditions for the sequence above, but it was not continuous. Can you please help me with such construction?

Comment: @user177196: Sorry: I accidentally left off a superscript in the last displayed formula, so what I wrote *wasn’t* continuous at $t=\frac12$. It’s fixed now: the starting point for the second ‘slide’ is now the end of the first one. You’ll need to make a similar adjustment to the ‘otherwise’ case of your formula.

Comment: @user177196: For the case $x\in X_1$, do everything exactly the same, except that instead of processing the coordinates in the order $0,1,2,\ldots$, process them in the order $k,0,1,\ldots,k-1,k+1,k+2,\ldots$, where $x_k\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Prof. Scott: thanks for your prompted reply! So for the case $x\in X_1$, should the sequence be: $x_{n}^{t}=x_k^{1-2^{-n}}$ for $n=k$ (assume $x_k\in Q$), and $x_{n}^{t} = 2(2^k.t - 2^k + 1)p_0 + (2^{k+1} - 1 - 2^{k+1}t)x_k$ for $n=\neq k$? Also, for the "otherwise" case of my formula above, $x_{k}^{(t)}=x_{k}^{(1-2^{-n})}$.

Comment: @user177196: You’re making it harder than necessary. Start with $$x_n^{(t)}=\begin{cases}2tp_0+(1-2t)x_k,&\text{if }n=k\\x_n,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ for $0\le t\le\frac12$, then for each subsequent interval $1-2^{-n}\le t\le 1-2^{-(n+1)}$ fix up the first coordinate that hasn’t already been fixed up. If $k=3$, for instance, you’ll first slide $x_3$ to $\sqrt2$, then in order $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_4,x_5,\ldots$. That way at no point do you have more than one rational coordinate.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm so dumb:( Can you please confirm if for $\frac{1}{2}\leq t\leq \frac{3}{4}$, $x_{n}^{t} = (4t-2)p_0 + (3-4t)x_{k+1}$ if $n=k+1$ where $x_{k+1}$ is the first rational coordinate that hasn't been fixed.

Comment: @user177196: Not quite: you don’t know that the first unfixed coord. is the $k+1$ coord. If $k=0$, you’re actually doing exactly what was done in the $X_0$ case, so you just fixed the $0$ coord., and the first unfixed coord. **is** the $k+1=1$ coord. But if $k>0$, then on $\frac12\le t\le\frac34$ you’re fixing the $0$ coord., since it’s the first one that hasn’t yet been fixed at that point, not the $k+1$ coord.

Comment: so do you have a concrete way to write $x_{n}^{(t)}$ for $\frac{1}{2}\leq t\leq \frac{3}{4}$? I think the continuity part will immediately follow once I got the formula down, but it seems too hard to express "fixing the first coordinate that hasn't been fixed" in terms of an explicit formula.

Comment: @user177196: If you want to be very careful about it, say that $x_k$ is the rational coordinate. Then define $m_0=k$, and for $\ell>0$ let $$m_i=\min(\Bbb N\setminus\{m_k:i<\ell\})\;.$$ Then the sequence $\langle m_i:i\in\Bbb N\rangle$ lists the non-negative integers with $k$ first and then the rest in increasing order. Now fix the $m_n$ coordinate at step $n$. That is, for $2^{-n}\le t\le 2^{-(n+1)}$, fix the $m_n$ coordinate. This will fix the $k$ coordinate first, then each of the others in increasing order. The `if` clause for $x_\ell^{(t)}$ will then be $\text{if }\ell=m_n$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Scott, I think you made a typo on the formula of $x_{n}^{(t)}$ for $\frac{1}{2}\leq t\leq \frac{3}{4}$. The term $(4t-2)p_0$ should be $(4t-2)p_1$. Is this correct?